# Consume a WCF service via HTTP POST and without a service reference

Tags: wcf, web-services

I am going to need a web service that receives a string via HTTP POST and processes it without any response to the client. However, since I'm not the one making the client (which will be cell phones) I am unable to use a generated client class to consume the service. The service would also need to be self hosted in a regular Windows service, if that matters.

As I'm not too experienced with web services nor WCF, I am frankly unsure if I can or should use WCF for this, but as it's the only type of web service I'm at least a little familiar with I figured it would be great to start out with one if at all possible.

I've been googling around quite a bit but haven't been able to find any good references to this, so I'd also be very grateful if someone has a link lying around to someplace that discusses it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need WCF Restful service with one way operation. Following link might help you:
[A Developer's Guide to the WCF REST Starter Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee391967.aspx#Y1481),